# Why is $ -\sum_{i \in \text I} p_i \log_2(p_i)$ maximized for all $p_i$ equal? Is it true if $|\text I | = \infty$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

Reading a text it is stated without proof that $$ -\sum_{i \in \text I} p_i \log_2(p_i)$$ where $\sum_{i \in \text I} p_i = 1$ is maximized if $p_i$ is a constant.

In the case of my theorem, the index set $\text I$ is finite.

My question is, why is it true that the above sum is maximized for all $p_i$ equal? Does it also hold if the index set $\text I$ is infinite?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\text{Entropy} = -\sum_{i\in I}p_i\log_2 p_i
$$
maximise as
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\sum_{i\in I}p_i\log_2 p_i+\lambda \left(\sum_{i\in I} p_i - 1\right)
$$
maximise the lagrangian
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial p_i} = -\left(\log_2p_i + 1 -\lambda\right) = 0
$$
thus
$$
\log_2 p_i = -(1+\lambda)\implies p_i = 2^{-(1-\lambda)} 
$$
thus is a constant.

To get $\lambda$ you use the other condition (for completeness)
$$
\sum_i 2^{-(1-\lambda)} = 1 \\
\mathrm{e}^{-(1-\lambda)\ln 2}\sum_{i\in I} 1 = 1
$$
or
$$
\lambda  = 1 - \frac{\ln\left(\sum_{i\in I} 1\right)}{\ln 2}
$$

Comment: Why did you use a clever form of 0 here to introduce $\lambda$? Also I don't think you should have a sum when you differentiate.

Comment: you are right about the later..as for the first bit I am just maximizing with a constraint $\sum p_i = 1$. I did notice another error as well. Cheers.

Comment: Oh duh of course. It didn't occur to me that it's a Lagrange multiplier problem in disguise.

Comment: No worries, neither would I.  It is just by chance that I have just finished a work research problem utilising Janyes probability problem ;) which maximised the entropy with respect to other moments beyond the summation of probability.

Answer (score 2):

since
$$f(x)=x\log_{2}{x}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\log_{2}{x}+x\cdot\dfrac{\log_{2}{e}}{x}=\log_{2}{x}$$
$$\Longrightarrow f''(x)=\dfrac{\log_{2}{e}}{x}>0$$
then use this [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)
$$\sum_{i\in I}p_{i}\log_{2}{p_{i}}=\sum_{i\in I}f(p_{i})\ge |I|f\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i\in I}p_{i}}{|I|}\right)=|I|f\left(\dfrac{1}{|I|}\right)=|I|\log_{2}{\dfrac{1}{|I|}}$$
so
$$-\sum_{i\in I}p_{i}\log_{2}{p_{i}}\le |I|\log_{2}{|I|}$$
if and only of
$$p_{1}=p_{2}=\cdots=p_{|I|}=\dfrac{1}{|I|}$$
where $|I|=card{(I)}$